# What might be causing vxworks and windows to ignore eachother

Tags: vxworks, hypervisor, windows-10-iot-enterprise, virtual-ethernet

I have a machine that boots (simultaneously) VxWork and Windows 10 IoT.

The hypervisor sets up two virtual Ethernet adapters. I can see that both exist.

[image: how the windows port is configured]
[image: how the vxworks port is configured]

The VxWorks VM is sending out UDP packets to the address that the Windows VM has, and there is a service on Windows listening for the packets on the correct port.

If I run Wireshark I can see the packets from VxWorks and they are being sent to the correct place, but the Windows service isn't picking them up.

[image: wireshark screen grab]

The Windows service picks up packets if I run a python script to simulate the data to be sent and tell the service to listen to localhost.

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I need to configure the Windows Firewall. I have turned it off for now and the connection is being established.